# how to parse xml into one page to another page?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

i used below code for xml parsing:

```
 var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("chapter")
                   select new CountryData
                  {
                      Title = (string)query.Element("title"),
                      Des = (string)query.Element("text"),
                      Position = (int)query.Element("position"),

                  };
        countryList = data.ToList();
```

how to navigate information to next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Navigation-in-depth--Navigation-Framework

When we want to pass some data between pages we have to:

- form a query string
- use the NavigationContext

For how to use the NavigationContext follow the link.

Comment: i understand the navigation between the pages.i used chapter tag to extract the title value.how to extract inner title value.please help me.